# ACL ordering and evaluation. what should take precedence Account or group, aco or parent aco

Tags: php, .net, tree, acl

I am following this [cake php acl model](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/theshz/2006/11/28/user-permissions-and-cakephp-acl) article to create my own acl implementation.

I have understood the concepts of ACO ARO and ACO_ARO. I want to implement the Check method which will decide whether the aro has access to the aco. since there are ARO trees and ACO trees, how do i calculate the most effective permissions for a aco to a aro.

Also i have found the below article which has check method implemented but that is in php
[acl implementation](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/unigue_/2008/03/12/toniacl-component-tutorial)

In short, what should take precedence Account or group, aco or parent aco.

something like this [article](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/secur-acl.html)

update
uptill now i have reached till here

i have made a accessControlEntry class as follows

```
public class AccessControlEntry
{
    public BsonObjectId AccessControlEntryId { get; set; }
    public BsonObjectId AccessRequestObjectId { get; set; }
    public BsonObjectId AccessControlObjectId { get; set; }
    public bool CanView { get; set; }
    public bool CanEdit { get; set; }
    public bool CanDelete { get; set; }
    public bool CanAdministrate { get; set; }
}

        public bool Check(Usercontext usercontext, BsonObjectId acoId, string permission)
    {
        //aco id is accessControlObjectId like in cakephp acl
        Account acc = _usercontextService.GetAccountByUserContext(usercontext);

        //getting ACE  eg X account has CanRead=true on Y object
        AccessControlEntry entry = _accessControlEntryRepository.GetAccessControlEntry(acc.AccountId, acoId);
        if (entry != null)
        {
            bool value = (bool)entry.GetType().GetProperty(permission).GetValue(entry, null);
            return value;
        }

        //account entry not found ...search in groups
        bool groupEntryFound = false;
        bool effectiveValue = false;
        Group[] groups = _usercontextService.GetGroupsForAccount(acc.AccountId);
        foreach (Group group in groups)
        {
            AccessControlEntry entryGroup = _accessControlEntryRepository.GetAccessControlEntry(group.GroupId, acoId);
            if (entryGroup != null)
            {
                groupEntryFound = true;
                effectiveValue |= (bool)entryGroup.GetType().GetProperty(permission).GetValue(entryGroup, null);
            }
        }

        //ACE found in group ..return most privilged value
        if (groupEntryFound)
            return effectiveValue;

        //entry not found for account nor for group..return false
        return false;
    }
```

I call the check method from other services ike this

```
Check(context,44556,"CanRead")
```

The check method looks for AccessControlEntry for the account, if it does not find any entry for account then it looks for groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the above information we can write some simple tooling, in my case I am working with a content management system so my ACL's are about page access.

First I define what my ACL entries look like ...

```
using System;
namespace Core.Objects.CMS
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a record on an access control list
    /// </summary>
    public class PageACLEntry
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the access control entry id.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The access control entry id.
        /// </value>
        public int PageACLEntryId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the page id.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The page id.
        /// </value>
        public int PageId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name of the role.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The name of the role.
        /// </value>
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the read.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The read.
        /// </value>
        public bool? Read { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the content of the update.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The content of the update.
        /// </value>
        public bool? UpdateContent { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the update meta.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The update meta.
        /// </value>
        public bool? UpdateMeta { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the delete.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The delete.
        /// </value>
        public bool? Delete { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the full control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The full control.
        /// </value>
        public bool? FullControl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I create a helper class to handle the evaluations ...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Core.Objects.CMS;

namespace Core.Utilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Tools for permission calculation
    /// </summary>
    public static class PermissionHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates the page permissions the given user has on the given page.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="page">The page.</param>
        /// <param name="user">The user.</param>
        /// <returns>the effective permissions</returns>
        private static PageACLEntry CalculatePagePermissions(Page page, IPrincipal user)
        {
            PageACLEntry result = new PageACLEntry();
            // start with acl for the current page
            List<PageACLEntry> acl = new List<PageACLEntry>(page.AclRules);
            // append all the way up the tree until parent == null
            acl = AppendTreePermissions(acl, page, user);
            // reverse the list so we evaluate root first then work up to here
            acl.Reverse();
            // because of the order in which these are applied the most local rules overrule the less local
            // the wider the scope the less it applies
            acl.ForEach(ace => 
            {
                // only apply rules that apply to roles that our current user is in
                if (user.IsInRole(ace.RoleName))
                {
                    result.Read = Eval(result.Read, ace.Read);
                    result.Delete = Eval(result.Delete, ace.Delete);
                    result.UpdateMeta = Eval(result.UpdateMeta, ace.UpdateMeta);
                    result.UpdateContent = Eval(result.UpdateContent, ace.UpdateContent);
                    result.FullControl = Eval(result.FullControl, ace.FullControl);
                }
            });

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Evaluates the specified permission level.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="target">The target.</param>
        /// <param name="suggestion">The suggestion.</param>
        /// <returns>evaluation result</returns>
        private static bool? Eval(bool? target, bool? suggestion)
        {
            bool? result = null; 
            switch (target)
            { 
                case false:
                    result = false;
                    break;
                case true:
                    result = true;
                    break;
                case null:
                    break;
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Appends the tree acl from the tree root up to this point.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="acl">The acl.</param>
        /// <param name="page">The page.</param>
        /// <param name="user">The user.</param>
        /// <returns>the complete acl</returns>
        private static List<PageACLEntry> AppendTreePermissions(List<PageACLEntry> acl, Page page, IPrincipal user)
        {
            Page currentPage = page.Parent;
            while (currentPage != null)
            {
                acl.AddRange(currentPage.AclRules);
                currentPage = page.Parent;
            }

            return acl;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if the current User can read the given page.
        /// Unless an explicit deny rule is in place the default is to make everything read only.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="page">The page.</param>
        /// <param name="user">The user.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// access right indication as bool
        /// </returns>
        public static bool UserCanRead(Page page, IPrincipal user)
        {
            PageACLEntry permissions = CalculatePagePermissions(page, user);
            if (permissions.Read != false)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if the current User can delete the given page.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="page">The page.</param>
        /// <param name="user">The user.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// access right indication as bool
        /// </returns>
        public static bool UserCanDelete(Page page, IPrincipal user)
        {
            PageACLEntry permissions = CalculatePagePermissions(page, user);

            if (permissions.FullControl == true || permissions.Delete == true)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if the current User can update the given page.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="page">The page.</param>
        /// <param name="user">The user.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// access right indication as bool
        /// </returns>
        public static bool UserCanUpdate(Page page, IPrincipal user)
        {
            PageACLEntry permissions = CalculatePagePermissions(page, user);

            if (permissions.FullControl == true || permissions.UpdateMeta == true)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
        public static bool UserCanUpdateContent(Page page, IPrincipal user)
        {
            PageACLEntry permissions = CalculatePagePermissions(page, user);

            if (permissions.FullControl == true || permissions.UpdateContent == true)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if the current User can append children to the given page.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="page">The page.</param>
        /// <param name="user">The user.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// access right indication as bool
        /// </returns>
        public static bool UserCanAddChildTo(Page page, IPrincipal user)
        {
            PageACLEntry permissions = CalculatePagePermissions(page, user);

            if (permissions.FullControl == true || permissions.UpdateMeta == true)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This now gives me all the control I simply pass that a page and an IPrincipal object and I get back an ACLEntry that represents the level of access.

I decided to further abstract away my security implementation by making the Calculation method private and only the CanX methods public.

So now it's as simple as

```
bool result = PermissionsHelper.UserCanRead(page, user);
```

It seems like theres a lot of code but if you take out the formatting and comments (to meet coding standards) there's actually very little code, and if you copy this in in to a class file in Visual Studio it's actually very easy to follow and maintain.

You may also note, not once do I pass in a repository or service class to get data, that's because I use this to build objects that are written using code first EF modelling an i'm using lazy loading, so your implementation might require a bit more than page.parent.AClEntries to go crawling up the tree.

Oh just in case you need it here's my page class ...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Core.Objects.CMS
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a managed CMS page
    /// </summary>
    [Table("Pages")]
    public class Page
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the page id.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The page id.
        /// </value>
        public int PageId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the version.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The version.
        /// </value>
        public int Version { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the title.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The title.
        /// </value>
        public string Title { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the template.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The template.
        /// </value>
        public string Template { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the path.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The path.
        /// </value>
        public string Path { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the parent.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The parent.
        /// </value>
        public virtual Page Parent { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the children.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The children.
        /// </value>
        public virtual List<Page> Children { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the content.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The content.
        /// </value>
        public virtual List<PageContent> Content { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the component stacks.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The component stacks.
        /// </value>
        public virtual List<Stack> ComponentStacks { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the acl rules.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The acl rules.
        /// </value>
        public virtual List<PageACLEntry> AclRules { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Very simple poco ... using the power of EF to do all my on demand SQL crawling. 
The one down side ... i doubt it's particularly efficient if you have a page deeply nested in a tree.

I'm still open to suggestions on improving this but this felt like the cleanest way to implement a managable solution at the time.
Now i have total visibility of the problem I can look to make those efficiency gains.

But at least you have a point of reference right :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem in .Net whilst implementing a content management system / document management system model.

I found that in it's simplest form there are effectively 2 trees and that to do on the fly "effective permissions" calculations based on inherited permissions is unhealthy for your app in terms of scalability however that doesn't mean it's impossible.

This means that you can basically calculate effective permissions based on current nodes only to simplify the model.

For example: (lets use "Pages" as nodes)

In the complex model to figure out the permissions a user has on Page 4 you would effectively take all the permissions assigned to Pages 1, 3 and 4 then do an "additive merge".

In the simplified model we would only consider permissions added for the user for Page 4

```
   Page 1
      Page 2 
      Page 3
        Page 4
```

To keep my problem as simple as possible and thus as bug free as possible I decided to go for a model where only a role / group can be added with a relevant acl entry to a tree node.

This meant to figure out what I wanted in terms of permissions I would effectively run a query like (seudo code only your implementation may vary):

```
var allAcls = "Select all ACL where PageId in (pagesToThisPoint) and Role in (userRoles)" 
var resultAcl = new aclEntry();

allAcls.Each(acl => {
  resultAcl.Delete = (acl.Delete > resultAcl.Delete ? acl.Delete : resultAcl.Delete);
  resultAcl.Update = (acl.Update > resultAcl.Update ? acl.Update : resultAcl.Update);
  resultAcl.Read = (acl.Read > resultAcl.Read ? acl.Read : resultAcl.Read);
         ....
});
```

That leaves 1 other consideration, deny rules, where the rule is a deny rule the typical convention is that it overrides an allow rule.

So go back round the loop again and evaluate for denies:

```
allAcls.Each(acl => {
  resultAcl.Delete = (acl.Delete == deny ? resultAcl.Delete == deny);
  resultAcl.Update = (acl.Update == deny ? resultAcl.Update == deny);
  resultAcl.Read = (acl.Read == deny ? resultAcl.Read == deny);
         ....
});
```

So you're basically saying get all roles for both user and page, where the page has an acl entry for any of those roles add it to the resulting permissions then remove any permissions where an explicit deny is defined.

I'm sure that can be extended further if you then wanted to rerun the process for user specific permissions match all permissions that apply to the current user for the current page and overwrite the role based set.

As a general rule of thumb I tend to go by the logic that the the more specific the rule the more relevant it is.

So you might say something like ... 
 All managers can access the whole site
 Managers are denied any rights to the Admin Section of the website
 All Sales can access the sales section
 All marketing can access marketing
 Marketing user "Bob" can access sales

the logic above would cover all of this and effectively apply access as follows:
 Users get rights tot he section for their department (sales users = sales ect)
 Managers get additional rights and access to all areas accept admin (IT only maybe?)
 Bob is our exception and although he is in marketing we grant him rights to sales.

What this means:
 1. Users can be added to roles
 2. Pages can be added to roles and the role in question is then given "acl" rights
      This means I can say something like: 
         If the user is in the sales role grant them "read, update"
 3. By definition Page as such is not "in a role" but merely knows how much access to grant a role
 4. Extending this model means you can specify acl entries for a specific user
 5. A user acl entry overrides a role acl entry
 6. Acl entries considered are for the entire tree up to this point
 7. A deny rule overrides an allow rule

So what happens if say the parent page says "Sales users are denied access completely" and then the page we are on says "Current User bob has full access"?

This is based on a choice either the developer / the business makes on how to treat such a scenario ...

My thought would be:
The user is more local in scope than the role 
The deny rule applies to the parent whereas the allow rule applies to the page
I would take the allow rule.

If however the Parent rule was for the user and the Page rule for the role was for the current page I would take the rule for the role using the same logic.

Much of this ACL stuff is subjective, I tend to lean on what people are used to, for example: file system permissions in windows, that way the app appears to act in the way the user considers "the norm", that will keep you from getting 20 questions in the future.

Mostly anyway.

Comment: Ive been having a right battle ... had it all figured out, had Ninject pushing the IPrincipal in to the Repository<T> constructor then overrode the relevant methods where I wanted to perform security checks against a particular ACLService, the problem I had is that my methods were intentionally designed at this point to return IQueryables so in my Service<T> which depends on Repository<T> i could "focus the query" a bit more before any actual DB execution, however the problem arrises when you want to append some complex business logic to your linq because EF can't map it to a block of SQL.

Comment: One other thing ACL implementations / Security models you likely won't find much on from "credible sources" by way of raw details because lets face it ... who's gonna show the world their security model? That's why I went for a "this is the observable behaviour" approach.

Comment: Please have a look at the update..Am i on the right track...i have removed the object hierarchy on the right side

Comment: wow thats a lot of code and you're still relying on "magic strings" i'll post my solution to this problem ...

Answer (score 0):

See this url this is cakephp 2.0:-

```
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html
```

Comment: Cake 1.3 is a bit dated now but the documentation still remains pretty much unchanged for 2.x. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html

Comment: pffft, i've already proven its easy to roll your own with very little code. Why pull in a load of bloat you don't need when actually all you're after is about 2 or 3 classes.

Answer (score 0):

I learnt a lot from [PHPGacl](http://phpgacl.sourceforge.net/). A bit of an old project now but the concepts are still entirely valid today.

Their [manual](http://phpgacl.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf) helped me understand everything from the basics to the more complex issues.

Comment: its always good to take knowledge from those before you and build from that.